# Behavior of .NET Closure - Possibly Related to Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, closures

I have a method:

```
private Func<RQ, Task<RS>> RqRsAsyncHandler<RQ, RS>(string pName, Func<RQ, RS> handler)
        where RQ : Message
        where RS : Message
    {
        var pInfo = new RunningProcessInfo() { Name = pName };
        RunningProcesses.Add(pInfo);

        return (RQ rq) =>
        {
            // I have some code here that uses pName, and it's working...

            pInfo.SetLastOp(DateTime.Now);

            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return handler(rq);
            });
        };
    }
```

I use reflection to execute this method, and take the result and pass it off as a parameter to another handler - all of which works exactly as expected / desired.

What isn't working is the line:

```
pInfo.SetLastOp(DateTime.Now);
```

As far as I can tell, it never get's called.  If I set a breakpoint on it, it's not hit.  If I set a breakpoint inside SetLastOp, that breakpoint isn't hit.  If I put a Console.WriteLine call there, it doesn't print (but a Console.WriteLine inside the passed-in "handler" does).

What gives?  Am I missing something obvious?  Is it related to reflection?  Why does that line of code appear to be invisible?

I have another version which doesn't wrap the call to handler in a Task, so:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return handler(rq);
});
```

is just:

```
return handler(rq);
```

and it has the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're returning a method delegate, do you ever _invoke_ the returned `Func`? That is: `var result = RqRsAsyncHandler("someName", someHandler); result();`?

Comment: Another possibility, regarding your comment that you have "some code here that uses pName, and it's working...", is it possible it's throwing an unhandled exception that you aren't tracking?

Comment: Yes.  And I can see the execution of "handler" happening.

Comment: No.  And I only mentioned that code because it demonstrates the closure is working as expected at least that far.

Comment: Not sure what else then off the top of my head other than your typical debugging quirks (making sure you're debugging/attached to current code, in debug mode, not release, etc which I doubt are the case here for you) Maybe try reducing the code to a minimal reproduceable example that we can copy/paste and run ourselves.